# Invalid Syntax In the if and else functions | Math Equations With Variables

Tags: python, if-statement, variables, math

I'm trying to create a program where the user inputs the values they know about the pyramid and get all the values easily.

```
NA = 0
width = 20
print ('Welcome To The \"Big Bertha Of Right Rectangle Equations\"'.rjust(width,'-'))
print("Enter In All The Measurements You Have")
print("If You Don't Have A Measurement Please Enter \"NA\"")
print(" ")
BaseLength = ( input ("Enter Base Length: ") )
BaseWidth =  ( input ("Enter A Base Width: ") )
PyramidHeight = ( input ("Enter Pyramid Height: ") )
PyramidVolume = (input ("Enter Pyramid Volume: ") )

if BaseLength == NA:
    print("No Worries We\'ll Find Base Width For You!")
    BaseLengthCalc = int((PyramidVolume / (PyramidHeight * BaseWidth) * 3))

if BaseWidth == NA:
    print("No Worries We\'ll Find Base Width For You!")
    BaseWidthCalc = int((PyramidVolume/(PyramidHeight*BaseLength))*3)

if PyramidHeight == NA:
    print("No Worries We\'ll Find Pyramid Height For You!")
    PyramidHeightCalc = int((PyramidVolume/(BaseLength*BaseWidth))*3)

if PyramidVolume == NA:
    print("No Worries We\'ll Find Pyramid Volume For You!")
    PyramidVolumeCalc = int((BaseLength*BaseWidth*PyramidHeight/3))

    print("Here's All The Calculations Boss!")
    print(" ")

if BaseLength == NA:
    print(BaseLengthCalc)
else BaseLength == BaseLength:
    print("Base Length" + BaseLengthCalc)

if BaseWidth == NA:
    print(BaseWidthCalc)
else = BaseWidth == BaseWidth:
    print("Base Width" + BaseWidth)

if PyramidHeight == NA:
    print(PyramidHeight)
else :PyramidHeight == PyramidHeight:
    print("Pyramid Height" + PyramidHeight)

if PyramidVolume == NA:
    print(PyramidVolumeCalc)
else PyramidVolume == PyramidVolume:
    print("Pyramid Volume" + PyramidVolume)
```

Statement expected between else and the variables, I am new, and just eager to learn, so please be nice! Thank you!

Comment: your "else" lines probably need to end in colons as well

Comment: Definitely need colons.

Comment: `else` lines don't have a condition.

Comment: ... and the backslashes at the end of some lines are problematic too, get rid of them

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried your advice and it didn't solve the issue. Thanks for the fast response time though!

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You should really check how if/elif/else staements work. And comparing a variable to itself doe not make much sense..

Answer (score 0):

```
if BaseLength == NA:
    print(BaseLengthCalc)\
else not BaseLength != BaseLength
    print("Base Length" + BaseLengthCalc)
```

What is that expression after `else`?  That is not Python syntax.
Perhaps you need an `elif` and a colon here, but the expression also makes no sense.
I'm also not sure what you're trying to do with the line continuation.

Comment: When the condition is the exact opposite of the `if` condition, it clearly should be `else:`

Comment: I agree, but this condition checks a near tautology `X == X` and negates it twice.  Unless OP is making a clumsy `NaN` test, I don't see what's supposed to happen.

Comment: That's probably a typo, he probably meant `else BaseLength != NA`

Answer (score 0):

The statement `else not BaseLength != BaseLength` should be:

```
# not !=  -->  ==
elif BaseLength == BaseLength:
    print("Base Length" + BaseLengthCalc)
```

(Note `elif` instead of `else`, and the colon `:` at the end)

This case will always be true though as you are comparing a variable to itself, so the `else` statement is kinda pointless..

Comment: But there's also a `not` in it. I think he was just really confused when writing that.

Comment: Yes, noticed it. Answer updated. Weird condition indeed.

Comment: I suspect he meant to just use the reverse of the `if` condition, and this is the end result of him trying lots of random things to fix the syntax error.